# Find and replace word if only its line contains specific string (Regex Dreamweaver)

Tags: regex, replace, find, dreamweaver

I want to use Find and Replace in dream weaver to find and replace only the words which their lines contain a specific string.

Comment: Examples Examples Examples Code Code Code Output Output Output

Comment: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/regular_expressions_pt2.html

Comment: Please be more specific on my case ,, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user3503851, Dreamweaver has a notoriously shoddy regex flavor. Nevertheless, here is a working example, tested in CS6.

Our test text:

```
My Untitled Document Is Here
My Beautiful Document Is Here
My Document, the Beautiful
```

The goal: replace "Document" with "Blog", but only in a line that contains the word "Beautiful"

**Search:** `((?=.*?Beautiful)[^\r\n]*)(Document)`

**Replace:** `$1Blog`

**Result:**

```
My Untitled Document Is Here
My Beautiful Blog Is Here
My Blog, the Beautiful
```

Comment: @user3503851 You are welcome. Hey, I notice that you haven't yet voted on StackOverflow. If this answer or another answer solves your problem, please consider "accepting it" by clicking the checkmark and arrow on the left, as this is how the reputation system works. Of course there is no obligation to do so. Later when you have more reputation you can also upvote questions. Thanks for listening to my 20-second SO tutorial. :)